# Java 9 project structure issue

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, web-applications, structure, java-9

I'm trying to create project with java 9, but there is something I can't handle with project structure.

[image]

What am I trying to do is to create one-module web application with spring boot.
But my Intellij IDEA 2017.3.2 refuses to compile project with this structure and force me to move **module-info.java** to src folder. Also it highlights my package names and wants me to make them like  **main.java.ua.com.vhsoft.legis**

It seems like others don't have such a problem with file structure (based on all java9 examples I've seen).

When I place my **module-info.java** under src folder and change all package declaration to main.java.ua.com..., it kinda works. 
... but looks horrible

I'll be grateful for any tips and recommendations. Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**
Looks like IDEA related issue. It starts with ***mvn spring-boot:run -e*** command:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following changed in **pom.xml** fixed my issue:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<build>
```

to

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
<build>
```

Comment: This is the default value, you should be able to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Using IntelliJ-IDEA, you might simply want to do this:

1. Select and right-click on the `java` folder.
2. Move to the option ***Mark Directory as***.
3. Select the ***Sources Root*** option.

Comment: I've read this instructions somewhere but no luck in my case. The problem was in pom.xml